# creating a shard collection using mongoose from node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a shard collection from node function. And I am using mongoose to do CRUD operations with mongo DB.

Below is the function which deletes the existing `names` collection and is creating a new collection.  **But not with shard key.**

```
names.collection.drop()
        .then(res => {
            context.log("Item collection dropped");
            names.create({store_id: "9718", item_id: "123"})
                .then(res => {
                    context.log("res", res);
                }) 
        })
```

Here is the mongoose schema for that collection.

```
const itemsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  "store_id": {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  "item_id": {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  "ext_description": {
    type: String,
    required: false
  }
}, { shardKey: { store_id: 1 } });


const Item = mongoose.model("names", itemsSchema, 'names');
```

Appreciate your time.

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is. Please explain what is it you want (to do) and what is happening. You can drop a collection and create a collection, okay. You can also shard a collection, but cannot unshard a collection. A collection which is sharded must have a shard key. A sharded database can have both sharded and unsharded collections.

Comment: I am trying to drop a shard collection and create a new shard collection.  In the code 'names' is a model for that collection. The query i used to create a shard collection is 'names.create({})'. But it doesnt work.

Comment: I think you can try the dropping and creating collections from the _mongo shell_, first. Also, make sure you have appropriate permissions to do those tasks. Please refer mongoose documentation on how to work with collections of a sharded cluster.

Comment: _"The query i used to create a shard collection is 'names.create({})'. But it doesnt work."_. Do you have an error message?

Comment: Sorry @prasad_ I was out of town. I am not getting any error. But it is creating un-sharded collection.

Comment: By _default_, if you create  a collection in a sharded cluster it will be an unsharded collection (and this will be created on the Primary shard). You have to _explicitly_ shard a collection. Here is the documentation on [Sharded and Non-Sharded Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/sharding/index.html#sharded-and-non-sharded-collections) _and_ [Shard a Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/index.html#shard-a-collection).